# How to simultaneously change the color and thickness in ContourStyle?

Tags: plotting, graphics

When plotting contours with `ContourPlot`, one can use the option `ContourStyle` to change the contours of the plot.

With the instruction,

```
ContourPlot[f[x,y],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},ContourShading -> False, Contours -> Range[1,10], ContourStyle -> ColorData[10] /@ Range[10]]
```

I am able to change the colors of the contours, but they are thin.

On the other hand, if I use the instruction

```
ContourPlot[f[x,y],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},ContourShading -> False, Contours -> Range[1,10], ContourStyle -> Thick]
```

I am able to draw thicker contour lines, however, they are black.

I would like to draw the same contours **simultaneously thicker and colored**.

How could I proceed ?

Mathematica seems to indicate to use `Directive[...]`, but I have not been able to use it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseStyle.html) to set the `Thick` lines:

```
ContourPlot[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ContourShading -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData[10] /@ Range[10],
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Alternatively you could [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) `Directive` over the colour list:

```
ContourStyle -> Thread @ Directive[Thick, ColorData[10] /@ Range[10]]
```

which will give the same result.

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Comment: This answers exactly my question. It is based on the fact that the same thickness of the lines is shared between all the contours. For my own curiosity, would you know how to adapt the thickness from one line to another, simultaneously with the colors ? (If it is too involved, don't bother of course !)

Comment: @jibe See my answer for that variation.  If you don't need that level of specificity I prefer `BaseStyle`.

Answer (score 8):

A working way to use [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Directive.html):

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> Array[Directive[Thick, ColorData[10]@#] &, 10]
]
```

[image]

Changing thickness along with color:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> Array[{AbsoluteThickness[#], ColorData[10]@#} &, 10]
]
```

[image]

The same result may be had using `{ }` or `Directive[ ]` (for both variations).
`Directive` should be needed only when providing multiple style rules that are to apply to all lines, like this:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue]
]
```

[image]

Whereas with `{ }` you would get cyclic styling:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
 ContourShading -> False, 
 ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I think my parents had that wallpaper in the 70s :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods LOL (really)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't have Mathematica 10, to get this new amazing wallpapers syntax ! ;)

Comment: @jibe I'm not sure if that's a joke or if the second code doesn't work for you.  If the latter, what version are you using?  Please try [this code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/54903/1) from before I replaced `Directive`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your two codes examples work perfectly well for me with `Directive[]` (which is what I had only tried.). Quite surprinsigly, I have Mathematica 9. and the version with `{}` instead of `Directive` also works (I just tried it.)

Comment: @jibe Okay, that's good.  I didn't mean to suggest that `{}` would *only* work in version 10, only that this is the only version I tested it in.  I see now that that comment caused more confusion that it might have been worth.  I'll remove it.

Comment: @jibe Please see my updated answer.  I think it will clear the confusion. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for this clarification ! As I always know exactly how many contours I am going to plot, I guess that using `{}` or `Directive` is then completely equivalent for me.

Answer (score 1):

One can also modify the resulting graphic directly:

```
original = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 10, ContourShading -> False, 
   ContourStyle -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"] /@ Rescale@Array[# &, 10], 
   PlotPoints -> 100];

original /. RGBColor[a__] :> Sequence[Thick, RGBColor@a]
```

[image]

The advantage of this method is, it also adjusts the thickness of lines in legend, while the solutions shown by Simon and Mr.Wizard doesn't, at least in *v12.2*.

Comment: I personally prefer using `Directive[]` instead of `Sequence[]` in a situation like this: `original /. RGBColor[a__] :> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[a]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Directive`

```
ContourPlot[x+y,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},ContourShading->False,Contours->Range[1,10],ContourStyle->Directive[Thick,Red]]
```

Comment: Thank you, now all the contours are simultaneously thick and red. However, I would also like the colors to change from one contour to another, as in my first example. Would you know how to adapt your answer ?